# Is the "poll" tag redundant?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let's nuke the catch-all tags](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/lets-nuke-the-catch-all-tags)

Surely all questions here are polls, in the sense that people vote for answers they agree with?

Comment: +1 This still confuses me a bit, see the comments to http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58/tag-consolidation-and-blacklist. Please note that this is not a duplicate and that this tag might need a full-blown own discussion rather than comments to a more general question... I would like to see a clear explanation for when a question should be tagged [poll] (perhaps to place that information in its tag wiki?) but I really don't see a reason why we need poll all over the place, in the current situation most questions miss this tag and this might not improve in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I certainly don't think that the 'poll' tag is very useful, I don;t think anyone is really going to search for questions through that tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Is everyone OK with the tag being removed?**

Quoting TheLQ's comment on an answer at [Adding discipline to programmers.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65437/adding-discipline-to-programmers-stackexchange-com/65440#65440):

> ... If you look at it, all subjective questions are polls, ...

As most questions could be tagged with [poll] and nobody speaks up it really seems like a redundant tag.

I have a strong believe people would agree:

The poll tag is

- a meta tag as it doesn't tell something about the content,
- redundant as it's an useless tag for the reasons described in this question and its comment.

**As of now, it's gone...**

Those that disagree should start a serious meta question with a reason for such tags to exist.
After waiting some days, a lot of people have agreed and nobody has disagreed...

Comment: Please, wait to a definitive decision.

Comment: Okay... Stopped retagging further to prevent having to rollback much. The problem is that I don't think that a definitive decision will occur as this question isn't popular at all... How much more time should I give this Q? 3 days? 1 week? ...? Although our comments has put the Q on top again. :-)

Comment: Moderators have tools to do mass retag.

Comment: Yeah, that might be a more efficient action for one to perform...

Answer (score 1):

If the [poll] tag was useful, wouldn't this question be tagged with it?

I also disagree with its use on SO, along with other meta tags: they describe the *poster's intent or motivation* rather than the *question's content.*  You could say the poster's intent is the question type (of which "poll", "homework", etc. fit), but those still aren't about the *content* of the question.

It was a long time coming around to this opinion, though, and it's broken on this very site: [discussion], [feature-request], [bug], etc.  These categories are needed on a support site (with [discussion] merely because we mix it with support), while they don't seem to be on a Q&A site.

Comment: @Roger Pate: There's a separate [support] tag.

Comment: @Simon: Feature requests and bug reports are also types of support.