# Bad-practice, good-practices, best-practices, practice and programming-practices tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I notice there are five tags:

- [bad-practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-practice) **(10)**, [good-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good-practices) **(18)** and [best-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) (536),
- [practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) **(9)** and [programming-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-practices) (195).

I believe:

1. [bad-practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-practice) must be removed in all cases and questions merged with one of the other tags,
2. [good-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good-practices) must either be merged with [best-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices), or if there is a subtle difference between those two tags, it must be explained in [good-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good-practices) tag which currently has no description at all.
3. [practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) must be removed and questions merged with [programming-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-practices).

Comment: There's also potential for further disambiguation within the [best-practices] and [programming-practices] tags, but I agree with your initial suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why should the [bad-practices] tag be removed.

Comment: @ChrisF: personally, I would tag a question talking about bad practices with [best-practices] tag, since both are strongly linked. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @MainMa Would a question asking if something was bad-practice be a valid one? There exist practices which are definitely bad, but there is no "best-practice" alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

This is all done: [bad-practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-practice), [good-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good-practices), and [practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) have all been cleared.

---

[best-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) is a tag that's been [nominated for the nuclear option](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/should-we-nuke-the-catch-all-tags). I've also added [programming-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-practices) to the list: I don't see it adding any semantic value to a question.

Because these are just catch-all tags, I'm a little hesitant to merge anything into them, but on the other hand, we're only talking about 37 questions tops.

1. [bad-practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-practice) isn't adding anything to the questions and can safely be removed. There are only 9 questions, so this can be done manually.
2. I'm comfortable with merging [good-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good-practices) into [best-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices): from what I can tell, they're used interchangeably (I guess it's a regional thing).
3. [practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) could, in theory, be used in the training sense, but in practice (no pun intended), it's added no semantic content to the questions it's on. These questions should just have the tag manually removed: I'd rather we didn't create a synonym for a tag that can be used in different senses, especially as a synonym for a honeypot tag like [programming-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-practices).

Answer (score 1):

I think that all of them should be removed.

I just don't see what value any of them add to a question (can someone explain their value?). Instead, use tags to describe what you are talking about, not some meta-information. My biggest problem is that what is considered "bad" or "best" practices change over time (do we want localized tags?) and vary depending on project and organization. All answers should be providing good (the best) advice and practices given the situation described in the question.