# Blacklist [homework]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-blacklist

[homework](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) was [recently cleaned up](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/removing-the-homework-tag), and as meta tags usually do it found it's way back to us, on at least three questions.

Can this tag be blacklisted, so it doesn't keep coming back?

Comment: Kill it! kill it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been added to the blacklist.