# How should I go about getting rid of bad tags en masse?

Tags: support, tags, faq-proposed, posse

I'd like to help deal with many of the bad tags on Programmers, but I'm not sure how to deal with them properly. What should I keep in mind as I work through a bad tag?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful list.  I will keep an eye out for bad tags and bad edits.

Comment: Why are you so obsessed with bad tags?

Comment: @JimG.Tagging is the [third most-talked about subject on our meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags), right after the on-topic definition and closed questions. Maybe you ought to ask yourself, "Why am I *not*?"

Comment: @JimG. Some of us are obsessed with [good tags](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/blacklist-good) too...

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: The 'good' tag is so absurd that indeed it *should* be expunged immediately. But why not leave it at that? Why are people "losing sleep" over sub-optimal tags, trying to round up posses to stamp them out?

Comment: @JimG. Take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which describes the problem with having bad tags around: in part, people use bad tags when they can't think of anything else to tag it with, and tags become honeypots for poorly thought-out questions. Minimizing those bad tags conditions people to make their questions work within the ecosystem we have: it's not coincidence we have a problem with general career advice questions when the largest tag by far for over a year was the lame [tag:career] tag.

Comment: @JimG. We like it better when information is organized, sub-optimal tags don't help and sometimes even hurt organization, hence sub-optimal tags must die. Let them live a bit longer, and they will soon become [broken windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: Since I strongly support fixing broken windows, I support this cause. You win. :)

Comment: @Mark Trapp: OK. I can appreciate the "honeypots" argument too. Thanks for discussing it.

Answer (score 3):

We're trying to come up with a structured way to deal with the bad tags through the [Structured Tag Cleanup initiative](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2886/8), but in the meantime, if you want to help with tag cleanups, the golden rule is:

> Only make substantial edits to questions.

To that end, these things are helpful:

- Retagging new questions asked that have bad tags
- Substantively revising a question to address multiple issues, from bad tags to bad titles to copyediting issues
- Small spurts of edits (5 or so) to prevent the front page from being flooded with old content
- Proposing tag merges and synonyms here on meta
- Voting to close questions in bad tags that have slipped through the cracks
- Flagging closed questions in bad tags that have no chance of getting reopened for deletion
- "Heroic" edits on closed questions in bad tags to attempt to get them re-opened

This is not helpful:

- Mass retagging in a short period of time
- Retagging questions without doing anything else
- Retagging closed questions that have no chance of ever getting opened again
- Retagging questions and replacing bad tags with [even worse ones](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/lets-nuke-the-catch-all-tags)

Definitely check out the [Structured Tag Cleanup proposal](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2886/8), but otherwise, please try to keep the above in mind if you've got an urge to clean up some tags.